# Is post foundationalism prescriptive?

Tags: epistemology

Is post foundationalism prescriptive: does it tell us anything about how best to come to knowledge, to learn or to act? Or is it just an abstract philosophical thesis with no bearing on e.g. science?

I'm asking because I got to thinking about deepfakes and fake news. If we cannot take anything for granted, maybe there is an analogy with post-foundationalist epistemology which also disavows taking anything for granted.

Comment: Does foundationalism or some other philosophical doctrine have much "bearing" on science? Or is it a rationalization after the fact? Post-foundationalism is foundationalism light, and considering its semi-theistic origins much bearing on science is unlikely. But, like others, the proponents offer their attempts, e.g. Clayton, Explanation from Physics to Theology.

Comment: aren't those pseudo paradoxes though? it may be that only this one sentence is true... i don't know why anyone takes that seriously